# Iseries JAVA program - Connection issue

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have been testing a Java program to connect from my iSeries to an Oracle database.
 If I hard code the connection string, everything works fine.
 If I pass the details of the connection string as parameters and then build the connection string inside the Java program, I receive a driver error.
 The hard coded connection string (which works) is..

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.65.7.124:1521:XXXRQT","USERID", "Passwd");
```

When I pass the IP address, sysname, userId & password in, I receive a driver error.
  The Java program is this.....

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.ibm.as400.access.*;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class TST19 
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
  {     



    String IPad=args[0];
    String Oserver=args[1] + '"';
    String UserName='"' +args[2] + '"';
    String Passw='"' +args[3] + '"';
    String ID='"' +args[4] + '"';
    String PortNo= ":1521:";
        String url1= '"' + "jdbc:oracle:thin:@";
        String url2= url1 + IPad + PortNo + Oserver + ',' + UserName + ',' + Passw;





//Let's get a connection to the Oracle server

        DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());






    System.out.println(url1);
        System.out.println(url2);       

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url1 + url2);


        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[1]);
        System.out.println(args[2]);
        System.out.println(args[3]);
        System.out.println(args[4]);

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    conn.close();

        System.out.println ("DONE!"); 
  }

}
```

I simply want the connection to work (ie get the Done message!)
 This is the error I receive...

```
 "jdbc:oracle:thin:@                                                      
 "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.67.7.124:1521:XXXRQT","USERID","Passwd"   
 Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver     
         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:446)  
         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:374)  
         at Phone_TST19.main(Phone_TST19.java:52)                         
 Java program completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: why do you added `ios` tag?

Comment: Why are you populating your string values with double quotes as part of the string?

Comment: I am not a Java programmer.  I got this program from here..https://www.mcpressonline.com/analytics-cognitive/db2/2110-techtip-populate-files-on-the-iseries-from-oracle-or-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

First, you are concatenating url1 into the connection string twice, once when you build url2:

```
String url2= url1 + IPad + PortNo + Oserver + ',' + UserName + ',' + Passw;
```

and again when you retrieve the connection:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url1 + url2);
```

Even worse, DriverManager.getConnection() takes three parameters, the connection url, user name, and password. In addition, while String literals need to be surrounded with double quotes `"`, the value of a String object should not include the same double quotes. So you need to redefine your String objects as well.

Try this:

```
String Driver = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@";
String IPad = args[0];
String PortNo = ":1521:";
String Oserver = args[1];
String UserName = args[2];
String Passw = args[3];
String url = Driver + IPad + PortNo + Observer;
....
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, UserName, Passw);
```

Comment: Well spotted.  I changed it as you said but the same error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

do this first so you have some output that can actually be useful in debugging.

```
class TST19 
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{     
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[1]);
        System.out.println(args[2]);
        System.out.println(args[3]);
        System.out.println(args[4]);
```